# Why does an implication whose conclusion is false mean a query?

Tags: logic, computer-science

In first order predicate logic, or logical programming, a query is a Horn clause without positive term, or an implication whose conclusion is false. 
For example, in Prolog, query `?- rainy(rochester)` means `false ← rainy(rochester)`.

What does an implication whose conclusion is false mean?
Such an implication is true if and only if its assumption is false. How can it mean a query?

For example,

In most implementations of Prolog, queries are entered with a special `?-` version of the implication symbol. If we were to type the following Queries

```
rainy(seattle).
rainy(rochester).
?- rainy(C).
```

the Prolog interpreter would respond with

```
C = seattle
```

Of course, `C = rochester` would also be a valid answer, but Prolog will ﬁnd
`seattle` ﬁrst, because it comes ﬁrst in the database.

How do implication `false ← rainy(C)` and query `?- rainy(C)` mean the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Horn clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_clause) are used in authomated theorem proving with the [Resolution proof procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#A_resolution_technique):

> Like in resolution theorem proving, intuitive meanings "show $φ$" and "assume $¬φ$" are synonymous (indirect proof); they both correspond to the same formula, viz. $¬φ$.

The proof procedure assume the negation of the formula $φ$ "to be showed" and find that the negated formula $¬φ$ is *unsatisfiable*.

If the procedure succeed, this means thatthe original formula $φ$ is a *tautology*.

Using the [*falsum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_(logic)) constant $\bot$, we have that $φ \to \bot$ is equivalent to $¬φ$.

In conclusion, using "$\text {false} \leftarrow φ$" as *goal cluase* is equivalento to "show $φ$", i.e. to prove $φ$.

---

Goals and queries are not the same (but they are treated similarly in logical programming).

See [Prolog : goals and queries](http://www.ablmcc.edu.hk/~scy/prolog/pro02.htm) : "A *goal* is a statement starting with a predicate and probably followed by its arguments. A goal is a statement starting with a predicate and probably followed by its arguments. This is similar to proving a hypothesis - the goal being the hypothesis, the facts being the axioms and the rules being the theorems."

"A *query* is a statement starting with a predicate and followed by its arguments, some of which are variables. The purpose of submitting a query is to find values to substitute into the variables in the query such that the query is satisfied. This is similar to asking a question, asking for "what values will make my statement true.""

If we express the goal : $\text ? \leftarrow \text {rainy}(c)$ as : $\bot \leftarrow \text {rainy}(c)$, i.e. as $\lnot \text {rainy}(c)$, using [Unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)#Application:_unification_in_logic_programming) we preform the substitution : $\lnot \text {rainy}(c)[c \leftarrow \text {seattle}]$ to get :

> $\lnot \text {rainy}(\text {seattle})$

and we can conclude applying the Resolution rule with premise : $\text {rainy}(\text {seattle})$.

This means that the substitution : $c \leftarrow \text {seattle}$ will resolve the query with the set of premises, i.e. that the said substitution will give us the result of the query : "$\text ? \leftarrow \text {rainy}(c)$", which means : "is there a value for $c$ such that $\text {rainy}(c)$ holds ?"

Comment: (1) Do you mean that using "false←¬φ" as goal clause is equivalent  to "show φ", i.e. to prove φ, instead? (2) How do implication false ← rainy(C) and query ?- rainy(C) mean the same? (see my update to post)

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure what your last paragraph means. What do you try to solve the query problem in terms of the goal? How do you use Unification and Resolution rules specifically?

Comment: @Tim - do you know Resolution algorithm ? and Resolution+Unification for FOL ?